# Body Layer not displaying correctly when using a FilterRowHeaderComposite

Tags: java, nattable

I have a composite layer for my columns to show a summary header and the column headers.

If I create a FilterRowHeaderComposite and replace the column layer in the composite layer, it displays the filters correctly but no longer shows any of the body layer. If I resize any rows it shows the rows.

```
bodyLayer = new TableBodyLayer < > (rowDataProvider, tableConfig, tableData);
summaryColumnHeaderLayer = new TableSummaryColumnHeaderLayer(bodyLayer, summaryColumnHeaderProvider);
summaryRowHeaderLayer = new TableSummaryRowHeaderLayer(bodyLayer, summaryRowHeaderProvider);
rowHeaderLayer = new TableRowHeaderLayer(rowHeaderProvider, bodyLayer);
columnHeaderLayer = new TableColumnHeaderLayer(columnHeaderProvider, bodyLayer);

final IColumnAccessor < T > columnAccessor = new IColumnAccessor < > () {

    @Override
    public Object getDataValue(T rowObject, int columnIndex) {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataValue(T rowObject, int columnIndex, Object newValue) {}

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return tableData.getColumnHeaders().size();
    }
};

final IFilterStrategy < T > filterStrategy = new DefaultGlazedListsFilterStrategy < > (tableData.getRows(),
    columnAccessor, configRegistry);

final FilterRowHeaderComposite < T > filterRowHeaderComposite = new FilterRowHeaderComposite < > (
    filterStrategy, columnHeaderLayer, rowDataProvider, configRegistry);

final CompositeLayer columnCompositeLayer = new CompositeLayer(1, 2);
columnCompositeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.COLUMN_GROUP_HEADER, summaryColumnHeaderLayer, 0, 0);
columnCompositeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, filterRowHeaderComposite, 0, 1);
```

***Examples***

**No FilterRowHeaderComposite**

[image: No FilterRowHeaderComposite]

**FilterRowHeaderComposite added**

[image: FilterRowHeaderComposite added]

**Row resizing with FilterRowHeaderComposite added**

[image: Row resizing with FilterRowHeaderComposite added]

I've tried using the filter columns and they are successfully filtering out the correct rows.

**Column Header Layer**

```
public class TableColumnHeaderLayer extends AbstractLayerTransform {

private final ColumnHeaderLayer colHeaderLayer;

public TableColumnHeaderLayer(final IDataProvider dataProvider, final TableBodyLayer bodyLayerStack) {
    final DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider);

    colHeaderLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayer(dataLayer, bodyLayerStack,
        bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer());

    setUnderlyingLayer(colHeaderLayer);

    final IConfigLabelAccumulator columnCellLabelAccumilator = (configLabels,
        columnPosition, rowPosition) - > {
        // Some logic to add a label
        configLabels.addLabel(CustomLineBorderDecorator.RIGHT_LINE_BORDER_LABEL);
        configLabels.addLabel(CustomLineBorderDecorator.BOTTOM_LINE_BORDER_LABEL);
    };
    colHeaderLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(columnCellLabelAccumilator);

}

public ColumnHeaderLayer getColumnHeaderLayer() {
    return colHeaderLayer;
}}
```

**Body Header Layer**

```
public class TableBodyLayer < T > extends AbstractLayerTransform {

@Nullable
private TableData < T > tableData = null;

private final SelectionLayer selectionLayer;
private final DataLayer bodyDataLayer;
private final GlazedListsEventLayer < T > eventLayer;

public TableBodyLayer(final RowDataProvider < T > rowDataProvider, final TableConfig tableConfig) {
    this(rowDataProvider, tableConfig, null);
}

public TableBodyLayer(final RowDataProvider < T > rowDataProvider, final TableConfig tableConfig,
    final TableData < T > tableData) {
    bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(rowDataProvider);
    bodyDataLayer.setDefaultColumnWidth(MINIMUM_COLUMN_WIDTH);
    bodyDataLayer.setDefaultRowHeight(MINIMUM_ROW_HEIGHT);

    IUniqueIndexLayer completeLayer = bodyDataLayer;

    if (tableConfig.isColumnReorderingEnabled()) {
        completeLayer = new ColumnReorderLayer(bodyDataLayer);
    }

    if (tableConfig.isRowReorderingEnabled()) {
        completeLayer = new RowReorderLayer(completeLayer);
    }

    if (tableConfig.isColumnFilteringEnabled()) {
        eventLayer = new GlazedListsEventLayer < > (bodyDataLayer, tableData.getRows());
        completeLayer = eventLayer;
    } else {
        eventLayer = null;
    }

    selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(completeLayer, false);

    if (tableConfig.isRowSelectionOnly()) {

        selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(
            new RowSelectionModel < > (selectionLayer, rowDataProvider, new IRowIdAccessor < T > () {

                @Override
                public Serializable getRowId(final T rowObject) {
                    return rowDataProvider.indexOfRowObject(rowObject);
                }
            }));
        selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration());
    }

    final AggregateConfiguration selectionLayerConfiguration = new SelectionLayerConfiguration();
    selectionLayer.addConfiguration(selectionLayerConfiguration);

    final ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);

    setUnderlyingLayer(viewportLayer);
}

public SelectionLayer getSelectionLayer() {
    return selectionLayer;
}

public DataLayer getDataLayer() {
    return bodyDataLayer;
}

public void setTableData(final TableData < T > tableData) {
    this.tableData = tableData;
    if (eventLayer != null) {
        eventLayer.setEventList(tableData.getRows());
    }
}}
```

**TableData**

```
public class TableData < T > {

private String xSummaryHeader;
private String ySummaryHeader;

/** Along the top */
private final List < ColumnHeader < T >> columnHeaders;

/** Along the side */
private DataGetter < T > rowHeaderGetter;

private final FilterList < T > rows = new FilterList < > (GlazedLists.eventList(Collections.emptyList()));

public TableData() {
    this(null, null, new ArrayList < > (), null, new ArrayList < > ());
}

public TableData(final List < ColumnHeader < T >> columnHeaders, final DataGetter < T > rowHeaderGetter,
    final List < T > rows) {

    this(null, null, columnHeaders, rowHeaderGetter, rows);
}

public TableData(final String xSummaryHeader, final String ySummaryHeader,
    final List < ColumnHeader < T >> columnHeaders, final DataGetter < T > rowHeaderGetter, final List < T > rows) {
    this.xSummaryHeader = xSummaryHeader;
    this.ySummaryHeader = ySummaryHeader;
    this.columnHeaders = columnHeaders;
    this.rowHeaderGetter = rowHeaderGetter;

    setRows(rows);
}

public String getColumnSummaryHeader() {
    return xSummaryHeader;
}

public String getRowSummaryHeader() {
    return ySummaryHeader;
}

public List < ColumnHeader < T >> getColumnHeaders() {
    return columnHeaders;
}

public DataGetter < T > getRowHeaderGetter() {
    return rowHeaderGetter;
}

public void setRowHeaderGetter(final DataGetter < T > rowHeaderGetter) {
    this.rowHeaderGetter = rowHeaderGetter;
}

public FilterList < T > getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(final List < T > newRows) {
    final EventList < T > eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(newRows);
    final FilterList < T > filterList = new FilterList < > (eventList);
    rows.clear();
    rows.addAll(filterList);
}

public void setColumnSummaryHeader(final String xSummaryHeader) {
    this.xSummaryHeader = xSummaryHeader;
}

public void setRowSummaryHeader(final String ySummaryHeader) {
    this.ySummaryHeader = ySummaryHeader;
}}
```

**Row Data Provider for the Body Layer**

```
public class RowDataProvider < T > implements IRowDataProvider < T > {

@Nullable
private TableData < T > tableData = null;

@Nullable
private TableCellLabelProvider cellLabelProvider = null;

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    if (tableData != null) {
        return tableData.getColumnHeaders().size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    if (tableData != null) {
        return tableData.getRows().size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getDataValue(final int columnIndex, final int rowIndex) {
    // Get data code here
}

@Override
public void setDataValue(final int columnIndex, final int rowIndex, final Object newData) {
    // Set data code here        

}

public void setTableCellLabelProvider(final TableCellLabelProvider cellLabelProvider) {
    this.cellLabelProvider = cellLabelProvider;
}

@Override
public T getRowObject(final int rowIndex) {
    return tableData.getRows().get(rowIndex);
}

@Override
public int indexOfRowObject(T rowObject) {
    return tableData.getRows().indexOf(rowObject);
}

public TableData < T > getTableData() {
    return tableData;
}

public void setTableData(final TableData < T > tableData) {
    this.tableData = tableData;
}}
```

**Column Header Provider**

```
public class ColumnHeaderProvider < T > implements IDataProvider {

private List < ColumnHeader < T >> headers = null;

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return headers.size();
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getDataValue(final int columnIndex, final int rowIndex) {
    if ((headers != null) && (headers.size() > columnIndex) && (columnIndex >= 0)) {
        return headers.get(columnIndex).getTitle();
    } else {
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}

@Override
public void setDataValue(final int columnIndex, final int rowIndex, final Object newValue) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public void setHeaders(final List < ColumnHeader < T >> headers) {
    this.headers = headers;
}}
```

**Config that was missing**

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, new FilterRowTextCellEditor(),
    DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.FILTER_ROW);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
    new PaddingDecorator(new TextPainter(), 0, 0, 0, 5), DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.FILTER_ROW);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.RENDER_GRID_LINES, Boolean.TRUE, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
    GridRegion.FILTER_ROW);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITABLE_RULE, IEditableRule.ALWAYS_EDITABLE,
    DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.FILTER_ROW);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(FilterRowConfigAttributes.TEXT_MATCHING_MODE, TextMatchingMode.CONTAINS);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(FilterRowConfigAttributes.FILTER_DISPLAY_CONVERTER,
    new DefaultDisplayConverter());
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(FilterRowConfigAttributes.FILTER_COMPARATOR,
    DefaultComparator.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your snippet as you created custom layer for almost every default NatTable layer. And I can't tell what you have done in there.

Two things that I notice are:

1. You introduce a new column accessor for the `DefaultGlazedListsFilterStrategy` instead of using the same as for the body data.
2. You are using the body data provider for the `FilterRowHeaderComposite` instead of the columnheader data provider.

Comment: The body data provider implements `IRowDataProvider` so I can't use that. Should I be implementing `IColumnAccessor` too?

Comment: I've added some more code for the layers. Let me know if any other information might help.

Comment: Like I said before, many questions. Have you implemented a custom `IDataProvider`? Are you using GlazedLists? What is `TableData`? Have you tried to use the column header data provider for the `FilterRowHeaderComposite`?

Comment: The TableData object is just used to store column headers, rows and row header getters all in one place. Makes everything a bit tidier. 
GlazedLists are being uses for the rows in the TableData object. 
I've added both providers and the table data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your question. I tried using the column data provider and had the same result.

Comment: Which NatTable version? Have you tried the new group header layers introduced with 1.6? Really hard to tell this way. Typically the issue is related to incorrect layer references when putting the composition together.

Comment: 1.6. I've tried this by removing the composite header and just using the FilterRowHeaderComposite and still get the same issue.
I've changed my row data provider to extend `ListDataProvider` now too so the filter layer now shares the column accessor. I'll continue playing around with it and see if I get somewhere.

Comment: Is the FilterList initialized correctly from the beginning? There are internal references that might be incorrect if you set the FilterList afterwards. And do you use a GridLayer to tie things together?

Comment: Yes I initalise a final list first and pass the reference around. Yes a gridlayer is used at the end to combine all layers at the end. `new GridLayer(bodyLayer, fullColumnLayer, fullRowLayer, cornerLayer, false);`

Comment: I found out the problem and it was separate from this. I didn't specify the text painter for the FILTER_ROW area. 
If you'd like to update your answer mentioning the painter/registry config I'll accept it as the points you made helped me narrow this down. 
Thank you for the help.

Comment: This sounds strange. The painter for the FILTER_ROW area is added by default via the `DefaultFilterRowConfiguration`. And from your snippets this configuration should apply. It is unclear from your snippets why that configuration should not be there.

Comment: I've copied in what was missing. It was the whole section of the config for `FILTER_ROW`.

Comment: I still don't understand why it was missing. Like I said, it is added by default via the `DefaultFilterRowConfiguration` when creating the `FilterRowDataLayer`, which is created by the `FilterRowHeaderComposite`. There is no option to skip that default configuration. So why is it missing in your scenario? You are calling `natTable#configure()` at the end of your composition with your custom `ConfigRegistry` instance?

Comment: That would be why. I'd removed the default configuration at some point while changing things around.